# Google Play Games error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred."

Tags: android, google-play-games

I am following this guide to implement Play Games in my App -> [Accessing the Play Games Services APIs in Your Android Game](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/init)

When I run my App I get "java.lang.IllegalStateException: A fatal developer error has occurred." on calling "mGoogleApiClient.connect();" and my app crashes.

I have no idea where the problem is. Maybe someone can help? Do you need some further information?

I have:

- minSdkVersion 16
- targetSdkVersion 23
- compileSdkVersion 23
- buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
- play-services:9.4.0

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ready. 
It was my mistake. There already was an GoogleApiClient because I said Android Studio to create AppIndexing.